# How long live global variables in a static library?

Tags: c++, memory-management, global-variables, static-libraries, undefined-behavior

Assume I have the following static library, implemented in C++:

```
int global = 0;

extern int foo(int i)
{
    global += i;
    return global;
}
```

And I use it as follows in my project:

```
#include <iostream>

extern int foo(int i);

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << foo(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << foo(1) << "\n";
}
```

This code prints out:

```
1
2
3
```

So, apparently, the global variable "survives" the function call, unlike when I would implement foo in an executable and call that executable multiple times, the global variable would be set to zero each time.

**Question**: How long do global variables live in a static library used like above? As long as the `main` function of the calling executable? Is it even allowed to do this?

Comment: It lives through the lifetime of the compilation unit that's using it. Yes it's allowed to do this, but it's bad practice.

Comment: `extern` should not be used on function definitions. It has no effect, and potentially confuses the reader.

Comment: @Brian You are right... I thought that I can use it to control which functions become "visible" for users of the library, but apparently, that's not the case. Is there a different keyword used for such a feature?

Comment: You can declare functions `static` in order to make them private to the translation unit. Declaring them in an anonymous namespace has the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of global variables being initialized before `main()` is entered and destroyed after `main()` exits.

The actual rules are a bit more complex, but in most simple situations like this that will cover you.

---

What you are referring to as a global variable in this case is actually "static storage duration object" with "global scope".

There are other examples of static storage duration objects.

```
extern int foo(int i)
{
    static int global = 0;   // marking this static inside a function
                             // makes it a static storage duration
                             // object that lives longer than the function.

    global += i;
    return global;
}
```